# Mongoose projection shows additional fields

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my Schema.

```
const test = new Mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
gender: String,
address: {
    Line1: String,
    Line2: String
}
});

let testDataModel = Mongoose.model('test', test);
```

I am trying to query like below. My intent is to get only gender field in the query output. But for some reason, I am getting an empty address field also. Can you please help me understand why that is happening?

```
let testList = testDataModel.find({name:"David"}, 'gender -_id', (err, record)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log(record);
      }
    })
```

Output:

```
[ { address: {}, gender: 'Male' } ]
```

Comment: Try to project this way `{ gender: 1}` instead of `'gender -_id'`

Comment: Tried that also. No luck